# Index JSON filename along with JSON content in Solr

Tags: json, solr, import

I have 2 directories: 1 with txt files and the other with corresponding JSON (metadata) files (around 90000 of each). There is one JSON file for each CSV file, and they share the same name (they don't share any other fields). I am trying to index all these files in Apache solr.

The txt files just have plain text, I mapped each line to a field call 'sentence' and included the file name as a field using the data import handler. No problems here.

The JSON file has metadata: 3 tags: a URL, author and title (for the content in the corresponding txt file).
When I index the JSON file (I just used the _default schema, and posted the fields to the schema, as explained in the official solr tutorial), I don't know how to get the file name into the index as a field. As far as i know, that's no way to use the Data import handler for JSON files. I've read that I can pass a literal through the bin/post tool, but again, as far as I understand, I can't pass in the file name dynamically as a literal.

I NEED to get the file name, it is the only way in which I can associate the metadata with each sentence in the txt files in my downstream Python code.

So if anybody has a suggestion about how I should index the JSON file name along with the JSON content (or even some workaround), I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: So how are you indexing today? How do you know which files to index, and how are you indexing them?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I haven't indexed the files before this, they were generated by somebody else. The files to index are within a directory, with different extensions like I mentioned. I've indexed the txt files, and now have to index these json files (which are pretty simple: they just have 3 fields: url, authors, title).

Comment: @MatsLindh The only thing I can think of  to tackle this problem is a pretty ugly workaround: to convert all the json files into csv files, and then to index it with the Data Import Handler with the LineEntityProcessor and the RegexTransformer like this:  ` <field column="rawLine" regex="^(.*),(.*),(.),(.)$" groupNames="filename,url,authors,title" />` But I'd rather index the Json files with the filename directly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There's solr clients available for most popular languages, so if you're going to write code to convert JSON to CSV - read the JSON and submit it to Solr instead as a regular Solr document. You'll have the filename available as well.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh, that's a better idea than converting the files into CSV. I'll look into the documentation for one of the Python client modules (there seem to be a few!).

Comment: [pysolr](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr) is the client most people use - it's now maintained as part of the django-haystack project. Leave a comment if you need help about how to implement this.

Comment: @MatsLindh, sorry, I did not notice your comment. Thanks a lot for the offer! I was a bit scared about Pysolr's lack of documentation, but it turned out to be easy to use (at least for simple use cases like this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MatsLindh mentioned in the comments, I used Pysolr to do the indexing and get the filename. It's pretty basic, but I thought I'd post what I did as Pysolr doesn't have much documentation.

So, here's how you use Pysolr to index multiple JSON files, while also indexing the file name of the files. This method can be used if you have your files and your metadata files with the same filename (but different extensions), and you want to link them together somehow, like in my case.

- Open a connection to your Solr instance using the **pysolr.Solr** command.
- Loop through the directory containing your files, and get the filename of each file using os.path.basename and store it in a variable (after removing the extension, if necessary).
- Read the file's JSON content into another variable.
- Pysolr expects whatever is to be indexed to be stored in a **list of dictionaries where each dictionary corresponds to one record.**
- Store all the fields you want to index in a dictionary (solr_content in my code below) while making sure the keys match the field names in your managed-schema file.
- Append the dictionary created in each iteration to a list (list_for_solr in my code).
- Outside the loop, use the **solr.add** command to send your list of dictionaries to be indexed in Solr.
- That's all there is to it! Here's the code.

  ```
  solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name')
  folderpath = directory-where-the-files-are-present
  list_for_solr = []
  for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath, '*.meta')):
      with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
          filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
          # filename is xxxx.yyyy.meta
          filename_without_extension = '.'.join(filename.split('.')[:2])
          content = json.load(file)
      solr_content = {}
      solr_content['authors'] = content['authors']
      solr_content['title'] = content['title']
      solr_content['url'] = content['url']
      solr_content['filename'] = filename_without_extension
      list_for_solr.append(solr_content)
  solr.add(list_for_solr)
  ```