# Apache Solr integration with MySQL

Tags: mysql, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to web crawling with Apache Nutch, so apologies if this is a basic question. I am trying to crawl data with Apache Nutch 1.X. The ultimate goal is to save the crawled data into MySQL, and fields such as the 'Title', 'Description', 'location information' on a page will be saved into columns in MySQL database.

I have successfully installed Apache Nutch 1.X and integrated it with Solr, and have also carried out crawling with it, so my data has been indexed in Solr.

The confusion I'm having now is how to get this data into MySQL, or just to view and process the data from Solr or Nucth. Though the indexing in Solr is quite impressive, I still need to get more fields and move the data out for processing in another code (I'm working on summarizing the data as well), and also store this data in MySQL, which holds all our projects' data.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: As far as I know you have to make the MySQL integration yourself with Nutch 1. Nutch 2 uses Gora, so you can define its connection string as using MySQL out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. I was hoping to use Nutch 1. If I can't get any suggestion on it, then I'll go on to Nutch 2.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673757/connecting-mysql-to-apache-nutch for a possible solution; seems like it's a rather manual process. If you instead want to extract your Solr index, you can use the `csv` writer with `rows=-1` or the `/export` endpoint

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. I came across this response and wondered if I could try something like the response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418495/index-json-filename-along-with-json-content-in-solr.
Extracting the JSON file from Solr into Python will work for me. I could then insert it into the MySQL database, or do anything else with the result. All I really want is to export the indexed JSON file from Solr.

Comment: The absolutely fastest way since you want the complete dump is to either use the csv writer or the /export endpoint - the latter is built for exporting large result sets.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh. I'll try this. Our result set is likely to be quite large as well though, as we will be crawling large websites.

Comment: Also @MatsLindh, how would you use this export handler in a code?

Comment: You don't really need to write code; you can just use `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/export?q=*:*&sort=<sort field - required>&fl=<list of fields - required>` - The output format is JSON by default. You can then parse this file in your code as you want to (for example by using a JSON stream parser). That way you won't have to keep any large files in memory.

Comment: The example has been lifted from https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/exporting-result-sets.html

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh. I didn't think of it! That'll work just fine.